# Downloading an Excel file from Glassfish using IE8 over SSL results in an error

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, jakarta-ee, glassfish, download

I have a Java EE application that generates an Excel file and sends it to the browser (Internet Explorer 8) over HTTPS. The user is presented with the usual IE "Open/Save/Close" dialog. If he clicks on the Open/Save within several seconds, everything works fine. However, if he waits longer (usually > 30 seconds, although varies), when he clicks Open or Save, the dialog just dismisses and nothing happens. I tried different caching headers (e.g., http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272359) and also set the `<property name="securePagesWithPragma" value="false"/>` in sun-web.xml according to http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1172 and neither helps. Here are the response headers:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Fri, 10 Jun 2011 09:02:45 GMT
Server: Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1 Patch04
Set-Cookie: SM_UID=[removed]; path=/; domain=[removed]
Set-Cookie: SM_USER=[removed]; path=/; domain=[removed]
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5
X-Powered-By: JSF/1.2
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=[removed].xlsm
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12
Content-Length: 44416
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8c887b2a53924d5484d31821f915.0; Path=/[removed]; Secure
Connection: close
```

and the error message:

```
URL: https:[removed].jsf
Content Type: application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12
Headers size (bytes): 2656
Data size (bytes): 8192
Total size (bytes): 10848
Transferred data size (bytes): 10848

Cached data: No

Error result: 0x800c0007
Error constant: INET_E_DATA_NOT_AVAILABLE
Error description: An Internet connection was established, but the data cannot be retrieved
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

**Update:**
I have an idea as to what causes the error. The download in question is initiated by a simulated click on a hidden button through JavaScript. I suspect, that because of this some thread is blocked while the Open/Save dialog is displayed and the browser is waiting for user input. Here is what I found through DebugBar for a download that fails:

```
Request start time: Thu, 16 Jun 2011 19:14:15
Connecting time: 177 ms
Headers exchange time: 64 ms
Data transmission time: **72849 ms**
```

I also have a similar page where a download is initiated manually with user clicking on a button. In this case the download works fine:

```
Request start time: Thu, 16 Jun 2011 19:18:57
Connecting time: 4 ms
Headers exchange time: 3384 ms
Data transmission time: **23 ms**
```

In both cases, I left the Open/Save dialog be displayed for about a minute before clicking on "Open". Notice how in the first case the `Data transmission time` is the whole period when the dialog was shown, while in the second case it is several milliseconds. I need to simulate a click in the first case because the file that is downloaded is generated asynchronously ([Is it safe to start a new thread in a JSF managed bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149919/is-it-safe-to-start-a-new-thread-in-a-jsf-managed-bean)).

Comment: Generally speaking, this should work fine. If you remove the Content-Type header does it work better? Have you used Fiddler to see what's happening "behind the scenes"? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/03/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx explains one common problem.

Comment: Eric, thank you for suggestion. I tried Fiddler, could not get it work with HTTPS, so I used DebugBar instead. I also looked at you link and others related to caching, this does not help.