# Mail Sending with a special thread

Tags: java, jsf-2, jakarta-mail

i have a jsf application running on tomcat 6.0 and somewhere in the app i send e mails to some users.But sending mail slower than i thought, it causes lacks beetwen these related pages.

So my question is; is that a good(or doable) a way  to give this proccess  to another thread which i create, a thread that gets mail sending requests and put these in a queue and proccess these apart from main application.Hence the mail sending proccess would be out of the main flow and doesnt affect the app's speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's definitely a good idea. You should only do it with an extreme care. Here's some food for thought:

- [Is it safe to start a new thread in a JSF managed bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149919/is-it-safe-to-start-a-new-thread-in-a-jsf-managed-bean)
- [Spawning threads in a JSF managed bean for scheduled tasks using a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499534/applicationscope-bean-that-uses-a-timertask-sheduler-good-or-bad)

As you're using Tomcat, which does not support EJB out the box (and thus `@Asynchronus` `@Singleton` is out of question), I'd create an application scoped bean which holds an [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to process the mail tasks. Here's a kickoff example:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class TaskManager {

    private ExecutorService executor;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
        return executor.submit(task);
    }

    // Or just void submit(Runnable task) if you want fire-and-forget.

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }

}
```

This creates a single thread and puts the tasks in a queue. You can use it in normal beans as follows:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Register {

    @ManagedProperty("#{taskManager}")
    private TaskManager taskManager;

    public void submit() {
        // ...

        taskManager.submit(new MailTask(mail));
        // You might want to hold the return value in some Future<Result>, but
        // you should store it in view or session scope in order to get result
        // later. Note that the thread will block whenever you call get() on it.
        // You can just ignore it altogether (as the current example is doing).
    }

}
```

To learn more about `java.util.concurrent` API, refer the [official tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).