# Can AsyncResult be thought of as serializable FutureTask?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I don’t understand an idea of AsyncResult class.
From the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) I have learned that it works just as FutureTask class (but AsyncResult is serializable, so it can be send to local or remote client).
However, [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/AsyncResult.html) says that this class' methods should not be called so I can only create and return instance of this class:

```
@Asynchronous
public Future<String> processPayment(Order order) throws PaymentException {
  ...
  String status = ...;
  return new AsyncResult<String>(status);
}
```

So what kind of object will client get?

Can I write

```
@Asynchronous
public  AsyncResult<String> processPayment...
```

?.

Will container do something to cancel asynchronous task after invoking AsyncResult’s/Future's `cancel(false)` method?

**EDIT:**
I have found answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149919/is-it-safe-to-start-a-new-thread-in-a-jsf-managed-bean/6158773#comment13349158_6158773).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the the rationale on the AsyncResult class documentation:

> Note that this object is not passed to the client. It is merely a
>   convenience for providing the result value to the container.
>   Therefore, none of its instance methods should be called by the
>   application.

Using the (correct) signature defined in your first snippet, a client will receive a simple Future as in :

```
@Singleton
public class AsyncClient{
   @Inject PaymentProcessor proc;
   public String invokePaymentProcessor(Order order){
         Future<String> result=proc.processPayment(order);
         // should not block.... the container instantiates a Future and 
         // returns it immediately
         return result.get(); // gets the string (blocks until received)
   }

}
```

Surely, if the container has not begun the method invocation (i.e the asyncronous invocation is still in the processig queue), `cancel(false)` should cancel the invocation (remove it from the queue), otherwise you should specify `cancel(true)` and check `SessionContext.wasCancelled` in the eventual processing loop of `PaymentProcessor.processPayment`